# Web service to connect to remote queue

Tags: web-services

I am developing a Web Service solution that is hosted inside a JBoss 4.2.3 sever (as the following) and my code connect to Remote JMS queue hat is hosted on another server(192.168.35.25)

```
 public static Context getInitialContext () throws JMSException,NamingException
    {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
        prop.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "org.jboss.naming");
        prop.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", "192.168.35.20:1099");
        Context context = new InitialContext(prop);

        return context;
```

### }

```
 public String SendMessages(String msg) throws ServletException, IOException, URISyntaxException {
    String body="";
    try
    {

        Context init =ClsSat.getInitialContext();
        javax.jms.Queue destination = (javax.jms.Queue) init.lookup("Queue/RemoteQueue");

          ConnectionFactory connectionFactory =   (ConnectionFactory) init.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
          Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection("un","pwd");//
          Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

;

          MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);


          TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();
          message.setText(msg);

          connection.start();

          producer.send(message);
          body = message.getText();


          session.close();
          connection.close();

      } 
    catch (Exception e)
      {
          return(e.toString());
      }

return body    ;

}
```

But I got an error ... RemoteQueue not bound
so any one have an idea or help about connect to remote queus throw web service
or any documents about connect to Remote queue on remote machine from web service hosted on local machine

Comment: On your example here do you have to connect to a next work drive and if so how does the connection string look.

Answer (score 0):

Can it be because of the wrong IP address in your getInitialContext(), please check if not you can provide some more detail.